# What happens if your handling editor leaves the editorial board?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors

I submitted a paper to a journal and after more than one year I got a positive report. I revised the paper as requested by the referee but when I tried to submit the revised version I discovered that my handling editor is not in the editorial board anymore. What happens normally in a case like this? Should I submit the revised version to a different editor?

Comment: Can you choose the editor of your choice?

Comment: No I can not. This is the problem. But the editor I chose when I first submitted the paper has been taking care of the submission up to now. For instance he found the referee. So I think the other editors do not know noting about the submission.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please [edit] your question to clarify: Did all communication happen directly with the editor, via mails to the journal, or via some online submission system?

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely hope there was more communication than just 'after more than one year'. It sounds like there are some organizational changes within the journal that may be working against you.  I've had that situation too, and it led to unreasonable delays in review.  I suggest you go straight to someone on the editorial board and politely ask for some relief. Problems within the journal editorship should not impact you so negatively, which it clearly has.  In my case, this worked, and the review was immediately reassigned to a new action editor and fast-tracked. Don't be afraid to speak up, just state the facts and be polite. The main point is to ask the journal what they think the best course of action is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the choice, you should in principle be able to send it to any of the active editors. At many journals, there is no "choice" in the editor and the paper will be reassigned by the editorial staff.

Answer (score 0):

As you replied to my comment that you can not choose an editor by your own choice. In this case, Editor in Chief will assign a new AE to your article. You don't have to worry about the change of AE, because new AE will make decisison based on your revised article and your response to reviewer's comments etc. 
However, you can also write a letter to new AE to inform him any delver that details about the progress of review process. Good luck!